# How to specify the schema in the Checks.yml in the Soda Core

Tags: soda

How to specify the schema in the Checks.yml in the Soda Core

configuration.yml

```
data_source  my_dataset:

 type: snowflake

 connection:

   username: USERNAME

   password: PWD

   account: ACCOUNT

   database: DBNAME

   warehouse: WAREHOUSE

   connection_timeout: 300

   role: ROLE

   client_session_keep_alive: false

   session_parameters:

schema: schema_1
```

And in checks.yml

```
checks for table_1:
  - values in "Year" must exist in schema_2.table_2 YEAR
```

Basically my table_1 exist in schema_1 and table_2 exist in schema_2

using schema_2.table_2  will not working because by default the schema_1 will be appended schema_1.schema_2.table_2

How to specify the schema for the table_2 in checks.yml

Answer (score 0):

So, In this scenario if even schemas of two dataset are different you should create a new data source for that and use `cross checks` to compare schemas of datasets.

link = https://docs.soda.io/soda-cl/compare.html#compare-data-in-different-data-sources-or-schemas